# Not using "admin interface" is a barrier for developing with Django?

Tags: python, django

We are up to developing an "accounting software" with Python. The software will based on SOA (rest) and hosted on cloud.
We are actually PHP developers but we'd like to switch Python for our future software. Our Python experience is 3 months and we developed a mid-sized social media software with Python / Tornado.

After googling about Python frameworks, we decided to use Django because it covers the libraries that we want to use as ORM, forms etc. and we think that it's communutiy is quite good compared with Flask.

Django presents an admin interface which we will NOT be using it. We'd like to develop our own class generators to create forms etc. Some say that "if you won't use Django admin interface, you'd better to choose Flask instead. Because it is more minimal and easy to use for Phyton beginners.

Therefore we are confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think my question is eligible to put back on because it covers the "specific expertise" article which is indicated on help center page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly *not* the case that the only benefit from Django is the admin. As you say, there are many good features: the ORM, template language, forms, authentication, and especially the third-party ecosystem are all great reasons to use Django. Now you can get all those same features with Flask if you're prepared to do some integration work, but the argument can just as easily be made that Django is better for beginners precisely because it does come with all those things built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: questions like "what framework is better" often doesn't have exact answer. It depends on many factors, and one of them is personal preference. So below is just my opinion.

I think, that django is the best choice in case you don't have strong arguments for other frameworks. Even if you don't plan to use it's built'in admin part.

Yes, Flask is simpler. But, django has more community, has more batteries.

Also, django will restrict your project architecture. I.e., you'll have to follow some approaches and project structure, that django provides. Someone can say, that it is bad. Well, maybe. But if you are new in python and web development, better follow it. Django is developed and maintained by good programmers. So, you will learn good patterns from working with it.